# Отправка переменных между двумя окнами Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Каким образом можно сделать перевод переменной из одного окна `Tab Bar Controller` в другое и отображение в нем?

К примеру в первом окне в текстовом поле мы вводим целое число (допустим 5). По нажатию на кнопку число "5" сохраняется в переменную и записывается в `Label`. 
Далее мы выбираем второе окно `Tab Bar Controller` и в нем прогружается введенное нами число "5" и отображается в `label` уже во втором окне.

Пробовал это сделать через `prepareForSegue`, но дальше переменная не идет.

Код приложения у меня конечно сложнее, но общая суть остается в переносе данных в другое окно, для проверки условия.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему лучше сделать какой-либо сервис-синглетон и через него передавать данные: число хранить в этом сервисе и оба экрана его читают и обновляют.
Читать можно перед показом экрана - `viewWillAppear`.

Синглетон сделать просто:

```
class TestService {
  static let shared = TestService()

  var number: Int = 0
}
```

Обращаться к числу можно так: `TestService.shared.number`

Если добавить делегаты (один объект) или обсерверы (массив объектов) для отслеживания изменений числа - будет лучше.

```
protocol TestServiceDelegate: class {
  numberChanged(_ number: Int)
}   

class TestService {
    static let shared = TestService()

    weak var delegate: TestServiceDelegate?

    var number: Int = 0 {
       didSet {
          delegate?.numberChanged(number)
       }
    }
}
```

Стоит обратить внимание что для делегатов и обсерверов нужно использовать weak ссылки - иначе сервис произведет захват делегата в памяти навсегда и произойдет утечка в памяти.
Список подписчиков сложнее - нужно использовать обертки над объектами, где внутри уже они хранятся как weak.

```
typealias WeakObject = WeakReference<AnyObject>
typealias WeakArray = [WeakObject]

class WeakReference<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value : T?
    init (_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func == (left: WeakReference, right: WeakReference) -> Bool {
        return left.value != nil && right.value != nil && left.value === right.value
    }

    static func != (left: WeakReference, right: WeakReference) -> Bool {
        return left.value == nil || right.value == nil || left.value !== right.value
    }
}

//MARK: Get values
extension WeakReference {
    func value<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return value as? T
    }
}

extension Array where Element == WeakObject {
    func values<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return self.compactMap { return $0.value(type) }
    }
}
```

2й способ взаимодействия между окнами - это обращение к ним на прямую (но такой способ плох и поломается если просто поменять экраны местами в табах).
У любого ViewController есть доступ к его UITabBarController, который уже хранит список всех экранов в порядке расположения табов.

```
(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? TwoViewController).number = 5
```